# Add id to ng-template with Angular Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm having trouble adding dynamic id to the heading template. I tried including an id="{{group.title}}" but it doesn't work. Any help or suggestion would be great!

```html
    <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" template-url="group-template.html" ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{group.title}}
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          {{group.content}}
        </div>
      </uib-accordion>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
        <div id="{{group.title}}" class="panel-heading" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
            <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" >
              <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
                <b>{{heading}}</b>
              </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
          <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: left" ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
      </script>
```

Here is the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/WbDY1S?p=preview

Comment: Demo doesn't use the script tag template anywhere. Not clear what your issue is based on what is shown

Comment: @charlietfl sorry about that i forgot to add the template-url but I'm trying to set the id for the first <div> element in the script tag template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `group` in that context as you have a different scope inside template.

`group` will be available in a parent scope, so you could use `{{$parent.group.title}}`

https://plnkr.co/edit/f7fHKohu7StKB4wJLeTv?p=preview

Comment: @RonT Try Chrome extension:  AngulaJS Batarang

Comment: awesome very useful tool!